# excel macro to compare a row with next and replace duplicate rows with blank

Tags: vba, excel, duplicates

image:
http://webserv-me.com/x.png

Hi, 
I've an excel sheet with 7000 row and I'd like please a VBA script in Excel 2007 to search in the **selected Column** and compare the row with the next, if any duplicate rows have been found, it should keep the original and remove the duplicate I.E: if we have 4 duplicates it should remove 3 and keep one, also the comparison with the next cell not with the entire colum
this image will describe what I need, 
I found this code but the comparison between the row and the entire column, So it gives me a wrong result.
http://www.teachexcel.com/free-excel-macros/m-23,delete-duplicate-rows-in-excel.html

thanks

Comment: this is a built in functionality of excel...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we started with this:

[image: before]

and run this tiny macro:

```
Sub DeDup()
    Dim N As Long, i As Long
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = N To 2 Step -1
        If Cells(i, "A").Value = Cells(i - 1, "A").Value Then Cells(i, "A").Clear
    Next i
End Sub
```

We would result in this:

[image: after]

Answer (score 0):

Select the Range of interest.
Click the Remove Duplicates tool on the Data ribbon.
Select the options in the dialog box to fit your specific needs.
Click OK.